# Middleware not following the condition - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication

I am trying to implement a user registration system in Laravel 5.7 where I am facing an issue.

I have two tables for Users- Admin(created by copying default Laravel auth), 
new routes, new middleware for admin. Every thing works fine while using guards.

I was trying to limit the user login by adding Approve/Disapprove functionality.

I added an extra column - admin(boolean) to the Users table.

In Login controller - LoginController.php Page, I added

```
  protected function authenticated($request, $user)
    {
        if ( $request->user()->admin != 1)
        // if($user->admin != 1)
        {
            return redirect()->route('approval');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/engineer');
        }
    }
```

so that, when the admin is 1 I am directed to '/engineer' where as in other case I am directed to 'approval'.

It works as desired!.

**Issue I am now facing is that if I try to access the 'engineer'
using user whose not approved I am able to access the page. I am not sure how to restrict it. The page is still restricted to public.**

Since the controller will be accessed by both the user and admin, I used __construct in the controller

> web.php

```
Route::resource('engineer', 'engineerController');
```

> engineerController.php

```
public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth:web,admin');
        }
```

My Understanding is that the condition is only checked when the user logs in and there after its exits.

Do I need to create a new middle ware in order to keep the authorised page intact?

I am a self learner and new to laravel. I am pretty sure that I am not following the right practice. I started something and was trying to follow it till I finish. Please guide me through it.

Along with it please let me how could I have done it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to define a Middleware that would check if the Engineer is approved or not.
Obviously, you would also need to keep that in an `is_approved` column for example.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckEngineerApproval
{
    /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! auth()->user->is_approved) {
            return redirect('user.approve');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then, add it in your `$routeMiddleware` array in your Kernel.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // 
    //
    'engineer.approved' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckEngineerApproval::class,
];
```

Finally, you can add the Middleware in your Controller's constructor as well.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth:web','admin','engineer.approved']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, 
I have a doubt here, while adding this 
public function __construct()

    {
        $this->middleware('auth:web,admin,engineer.approved');
    }

 'web', by default permit the users to access the page rgt?. 
When I try removing the web, I am getting Auth guard [engineer.approved] is not defined.

This is just my understanding, please correct me if  am wrong

Comment: `auth:web` means that the user needs to be logged in to access the page.

Comment: Also `$this->middleware()` takes an array of middlewares. I updated the constructor.

Comment: I changed the constructor to public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth:web,admin','engineer.approved']);
}
still the page is not redirecting

Comment: Could you `dd(auth()->user->is_approved)` in your middleware and let us know the output?

Comment: No worries Mozammil, I figured out what the issue was !! Thank you very much for your prompt response. I mean it.

The issue was with  if (! auth()->user->is_approved) {} in the middleware, I updated it to  if ( auth()->user->is_approved) {}. It's now redirecting the page back . 
Thanks a lot again.I will update the answer for you